# Can't figure out how to use floats and fixed positioning

Tags: html, css, css-float, css-position

I am developing a mobile website and I want a fixed navigation bar that looks like so...[image]

Unfortunately I haven't been able to achieve this with fixed positioning, such as in the code below. What ends up happening is everything collapses on top of each other to the left of the screen. I tried to see if clearing the float property after each image would help but it was to no avail. What will get this working? And yes I know styling in the html page isn't good practice, I will be creating stylesheets when I have finished debugging.

```
echo "<div style='text-align:center;background-color:#FFFFFF;position:fixed;'>".
        "<img style='float:left;' id='showLeft' src='slideBtn.png' />".
        "<img src='assets/ladle_bnr_mini.png' />".
        "<img style='float:right;' src='homeBtn.png' />".
     "</div>";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting `width=100%` on your container `div`

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XNNB8/)

Answer (score 0):

For a child to be able to be floated, the parent div must have a width set. Think about it... float left/right moves the child to the respective edges of the parent. If the parent has no edges, how can the children be float with respect to the edges? tiny sauce has the right answer.